# Symfony4 : Where is the assets folder?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am following a course about Symfony 4

According to the course I should have an assets folder, but I don't have one

image of my project

[image]

Comment: Directly in the public folder

Comment: Which course are you following? Why cant't you just create the folder yourself? What did you do to create the symfony project?

Comment: you mean that i should put my css & js fles in public folder?

Comment: this is how i created the project : composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton symbnb ~4.4

Comment: public/assets/{css} or public/assets/{js}, it's like you want but it's the minimum good practice

Comment: May be you need to install webpack-encore...it will create an assets folder. composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
 yarn install

Comment: Take a look at this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

Answer (score 3):

Install WebpackEncoreBundle. This will trigger Symfony Flex to create the assets folder for you.

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

Comment: Maybe you could precise that the folder will be created thanks to symfony flex which  will execute the webpack-encore-bundle recipe.

Comment: Mentioned about Symfony Flex.